# JQuery UI Slider scope

Tags: jquery, user-interface, sliders

I'm using JQuery's slider widget with non-linear values.  Basically, I have my slider set up like this

```
function configSlider(p_propertyName, p_sliderSteps) {

var slider_values = p_sliderSteps.split(',');

//build slider
var slider_selector = "#slider_" + p_propertyName;

var slider = $(slider_selector).slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: slider_values.length,
change: function (event, ui) {
        calculateSomething(
            $('#slider1').slider_values[$('#slider1').slider('value')],
            $('#slider2').slider_values[$('#slider2').slider('value')], 
            $('#slider3').slider_values[$('#slider3').slider('value')]);
    },
}
```

var slider_values has the actual values of the slider.  I need the values of two other sliders as well passed into calculateSomething above.  I know why this won't work but are there any solutions that would be similar to mine?

Is there anyway to create a new var within the slider object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [jQuery's `data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to assign arbitrary data to an element:

```
$("#slider1").data("slider_values", slider_values);
```

And then, to retrieve it:

```
var slider1Values = $("#slider1").data("slider_values");
```